convexity of a curve
I aim to determine the specific conditions on constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ that guarantee the following curve is both convex and smooth:
$r = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\theta-\hat{\theta})+b^2\sin^2(\theta-\hat{\theta})}} + c\cos(\theta-\hat{\theta})$
where $\hat{\theta}$ represents the angle with the $x$-axis and $\theta$ is the counterclockwise rotation angle. While I've explored various cases graphically using GeoGebra, I seek a formal mathematical proof to establish the exact conditions for convexity and smoothness, ensuring the curve is free from self-intersections and is differentiable.
My attempt: Certainly, one method is to analyze the curvature of the curve. A curve is convex if its curvature $k$ is always non-negative, where
$κ = (r^2 + 2(dr/d\theta)^2 - r(d^2r/d\theta^2)) / (r^2 + (dr/d\theta)^2)^{3/2}$.
Now, I have no idea how to find conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$.

How does that equation describe a curve? Are they polar coordinates?

Yes, in polar coordinates actually.
